# Position Toolbar on top of the screen with correct shadow in the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, toolbar

I have navigation controller based app and one viewcontroller presents modally graph in a landscape mode. I then add Toolbar with Done button to dismiss the graph vc and return to navigation and portrait mode.

I can't figure out how to position the Toolbar on top of the graph viewcontroller with correct shadow on the bottom of the toolbar. So far I have this code to add the toolbar to the bottom position, which has default shadow on the top of the toolbar. Is it allowed to have toolbar on top of the screen? For the reason of forced orientation rotation I cannot use navigation controller with the graph vc. Platform is iOS7 and iPhone only. Thanks.

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.width - 44.0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 44.0)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];

toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceButtonItem, doneButtonItem, nil];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your frame is looks a bit strange. You are calculating the y position from the view width and the width from the view height.

Maybe you have to specify that the toolbar is on top using the `UIBarPositioning` protocol.

```
UIImage *shadow = [toolbar shadowImageForToolbarPosition: UIBarPositionAny];
[toolbar setShadowImage:shadow forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached];
```

Next Edit:

This is what the documentation has to say about the iOS 7 UIToolbar:

> **`UIBarPositionTop`**
>   Specifies that the bar is at the top of its containing view.
>       The system uses this as a hint to draw directional decoration accordingly. For example, any shadow would be drawn below the bar.
>       **Instances of `UIToolbar` do not appear with this position on iPhone, but they can on iPad.**
>       Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
>       Declared in `UIBarCommon.h`.

Maybe toolbars are not meant to be used on top. However, you can simply add a shadow with `addSubview:`

Comment: The graph viewcontroller is presented in landscape, therefore I think the width and height are swapped I hope?

Comment: See my amended answer.

Comment: I tried this and xcode complains 'Assignment to readonly property' :(

Comment: OK, I had to figure out how to properly set this. The problem could be to get the default shadow image. You can always use your own.

Comment: I am apparently struggling to set my own shadow image, looks like the default is still being used. I will keep trying, but the shadow is always on top, never appears on the bottom of the bar, when I move the bar.

Comment: It seems the toolbar is not really designed to be used on top. Maybe you can just use addSubview. (I still think in view of my effort an up-vote is in order.)

Comment: Looks like the right approach, or I will rethink my design. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the method

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
```

from of `UIToolbarDelegate` protocol.